# Mysql can't assign foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hi I am trying to make `course_code` a foreign key, which is inside of my module table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE course (
code CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
credits TINYINT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT course_pk PRIMARY KEY (code));

CREATE TABLE module (
code CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
cost DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
credits TINYINT NOT NULL,
course_code CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT module_pk PRIMARY KEY (code),
CONSTRAINT module_fk FOREIGN KEY (course_code) 
    REFERENCES course(code));
```

The module table course_code references the course tables code column, but I cannot seem to get this to work, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What error do you get when you try?

Comment: how it doesn't work? how do you test it?

Comment: Your code worked for me without a single modification. What is the issue/error you are facing?

Comment: Ahh yes sorry I've fixed this now, strange, a foreign key wasn't being assigned/showing up on phpmyadmin but it should have been, I dropped the table and repaired it and this fixed the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it makes a difference what they are called but can't you rename 'code' in the course table to course_code?

Comment: No, I don't think it matters nor do I think that will make a difference